# doorkeeper gem gives "invalid_client" after successfully validated username and password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

http://localhost:3000/oauth/token

```
{
"error": "invalid_client",
"error_description": "Client authentication failed due to unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method."
}
```

while implementing doorkeeper..

**Started POST "/oauth/token" for ::1 at 2021-06-13 19:56:20 +0530
Processing by Doorkeeper::TokensController#create as */*
Parameters: {"grant_type"=>"password", "username"=>"bhagwan", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
User Load (7.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ? [["email", "bhagwan"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in '
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1654ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 28.7ms | Allocations: 5869)**

in doorkeeper.rb

```
grant_flows %w[password]

resource_owner_from_credentials do
User.find_by(email: params[:username])
&.authenticate(params[:password]) || nil
end
```

Comment: I think I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: I ran into this issue and it turned out I had enabled `hash_application_secrets` for doorkeeper. Then after creating a `Doorkeeper::Application` I was grabbing the secret directly from the database - which is now a hash of the secret - and passing that hashed value as the client secret when trying to obtain a token. Doorkeeper then hashes that value again when it tries to auth the client, causing the above failure. It's one possible way for the above error to arise (I really wish I had someone to blame other than myself)

Answer (score 8):

In my case, it was because the application is `private` by default. Had to update the application to be public with `update!(confidential: false)`.Since Doorkeeper `5.0.0` applications are private by default ([reference](https://changelogs.md/github/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/)).

Comment: Super important answer! I could have saved me a lot time if this would have been more documented.

Comment: my god, I just spent two hours debugging this, would never have suspected this bit.

Answer (score 6):

You can use skip_client_authentication_for_password_grant config option to skip client authentication for your case:

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  skip_client_authentication_for_password_grant true
end
```

Comment: if you do this, you should be aware that `Starting from 5.5.0 RC1, Doorkeeper requires client authentication for Resource Owner Password Grant
as stated in the OAuth RFC. You have to create a new OAuth client (Doorkeeper::Application) if you didn't have it before and use 
client credentials in HTTP Basic auth if you previously used this grant flow without client authentication.

To opt-out of this you could set the "skip_client_authentication_for_password_grant" configuration option
to "true", but note that this is in violation of the OAuth spec and represents a security risk.`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error (`client_error`) because i was on version 5.6.0.  when using `grant_type: password`

```
doorkeeper the authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server
```

downgrading to 5.4.0 made it work. I didn't see any part in the documentation that stated this. It was really annoying to do trial and error